# DataMapper => One-to-Many filter

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper, one-to-many

```
class Task
  include DataMapper::Resource
  has 1, :list, :through => Resource
end

class List
  include DataMapper::Resource
  has n, :tasks, :through => Resource
end
```

A list has many tasks. Suppose I have a task with id = 1.

How do I do to find the list that has this task?

I tried : List.first(:tasks => task) but it always returns nil.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about `Task.first(:id => 1).list`? By the way, you should really change the definitions of your models. I recommend you to read the datamapper documentation [thoroughly](http://datamapper.org/docs/associations).

```
class Task
  include DataMapper::Resource

  belongs_to :list
end

class List
  include DataMapper::Resource

  has n, :tasks
end
```

Doesn't that look much nicer? Oh and I hope you defined keys. These are important for well working associations. And if `id` is the key for `Task` your query would simplify to `Task.get(1).list`.

Answer (score 0):

You can used a nested condition like this:

```
List.first(:tasks => { :id => task.id })
```

but given a task it would be simpler to use `task.list`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have has 1 through resource? I would do Task.belongs_to :list and then List.has n, :tasks so you could write:

```
List.first :"tasks.id" => task.id
```

Although if you already got the task then it's simpler to just write task.list :)